# Wikipedia API Extraction of abstracts in 2 languages

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am trying to connect 2 API queries.

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Albert+Einstein&format=json`

Where I search for article descriptions and

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllang=de&titles=Companion%20dog`

Where I retrieve the name of the article in another language (here German).

Is there a way to connect them to retrieve description data both in English and German?

1. I have tried connecting them via "generators" and I seem to not understand how to apply it here.
2. I also tried inputting another query after extracting names in 2 languages (searching for descriptions). However, the names are sometimes formatted so that I cannot reuse them in the query.

Answer (score 0):

No. The description is a snippet from the start of the article. If you want a German description, you need to get it from the German Wikipedia (ie. a different API endpoint).